# C - words that start and end with the same letter

Tags: c, string, strtok

I've recently started learning C, and stumbled upon this exercise. I'm trying to find words that all start and end with the same letter. Sounded easy enough, yet I can't figure out how to make my program repeat the operation on every word in the array.

After browsing the web I decided to use `strtok`, separate the array into words and then check for every word whether it starts and ends with the same letter. I ended up with this code, but it's not working, yet the compiler doesn't show any problems as well.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main(){
    int i;
    int found = 0;
    char arr[1000];
    char *token;
    const char s[2] = " ";

    printf("Write your line:\n");
    scanf("%s", arr);
    token = strtok(arr, s);

    while(token!=NULL){
        if(token[0] == (strlen(token)-1)){
            found++;
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }

    if(found > 0){
        printf("Found %d words that start and end with the same letter.\n", found);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong? I've been looking at it for hours and I have no idea what is the problem.

Comment: How about ```if(token[0] == token[strlen(token)-1])``` ?

Comment: Also `scanf("%s", arr);` Always accept only one word.

Comment: @Ronald I tried it but it only works for the first word, neglects the rest

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so you're saying that if I write "one twot three" scanf will only accept "one"? I thought it was supposed to accept the whole string

Comment: yes, try Change `scanf("%s", arr);` to `scanf("%999[^\n]", arr);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY THANK YOU! works now! :) could you only explain to me what was it exactly? by writing that I just accepted the entire string instead of one word, correct?

Comment: `%s` of `scanf` makes white-spaces character be the end of input. So the space is not included. `%[^\n]` accepts non-newline as input.

Answer (score 0):

Change the scanf to gets and

```
f(token[0] == token[strlen(token)-1]
```

scanf considers white spaces as the end of the input provided.You can also use the specifier %[^\n] under scanf, which basically tells scanf to scan the input until "\n" occurs.
 
The drawback of %[^\n] is that, it would not work if you are trying to run the program multiple times, since, scanf acquires its input from stdin.Since the last character in stdin would be the last "\n" or enter you provided, it would basically continue to skip, the next input, making gets() the better option.